# What is the best way to do a timeout in .net?

Tags: .net, timeout

I'm a new student developing my first program.

My display:
*Device connected via USB cable in a laptop
*(Optional) Another laptop can be connected via TCP/IP in the first laptop

What my program does?
I can control a device remotely through a `.exe file`(located in my c:) by prompt. Ex:

```
    Dim myProcess as Process = New Process
    Dim command, ip as String
    Dim runLocal as Boolean
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe"
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    myProcess.Start()
    Dim sIn As System.IO.StreamWriter = myProcess.StandardInput
    sIn.Write("cd c:\" & System.Environment.NewLine)
    If runLocal = True Then
        sIn.Write("myexeFile " & commandCMD & System.Environment.NewLine)
    Else
        sIn.Write("myexeFile " & commandCMD & " " & ip & System.Environment.NewLine)
   End If
```

What I need to do to execute my program:
1. Run the device's software in the first laptop
2. After, run my own program (Can be execute directly in the first laptop or another one connected via TCP/IP cable, this is why I have the `runLocal` to change if it's running local or not

My problem:
I don't have the source code of this file, I just know that I can only send the command and this file wait for a reply. If there is no reply my application will keep waiting (the file doesn't have an own timeout)

When the problem occurs:
1. If the device it's not connected with the first laptop
2. If the device's software it's not running in the first laptop

What I want:
I would like to avoid sudden stops creating my own timeout

Summarizing: what is the best way to do a timeout in .net?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't really do much, just call a program called myexeFile. I would think that myexeFile should be checking to see if the "device" exists, or at least have its own timeout. If it doesn't and if you don't have the source code so you can fix it, perhaps the best approach is for you to check if the "device" exists before you call myexeFile.

Comment: I don't have the source code from this file. I just know that this file send the command and wait the reply, if there is no reply my application will keep waiting (file doesn't have an own timeout) and I would like to avoid this creating my own timeout

Comment: So try the second part of my comment. Find out if the "device" is working before calling the program. How you do that would depend on what the "device" is, how it is connected and what you are trying to do with it. You might want to edit your question to include that information.

Comment: Understood :) But I really need a timeout in that line. My program it's a little bit more complex...I'll edit my question with more details

Comment: @Blackwood now it's complete...sorry for the superficiality